# Magento2 How to Get ID of Street Address from Billing Address Using UiRegistry?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

I want to get the uid of billing address's street address at checkout page. I got the name of the field but getting the error when trying to get the uid of the field.
For getting the name i used the following code:

```
 uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields.street.0').name;
```

**The same way i tried for uid:**

```
uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields.street.0').uid;
```

But getting this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ks7M.png

**Also i try this:**

```
uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields.street').elems()[0].uid;
```

**But getting this error:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkGfF.png

Any suggestion to get the uid of billing address's street address at checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next option:

```
require('uiRegistry').filter('dataScope = billingAddress' + require('Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote').paymentMethod().method + '.street.0')[0].uid
```

or:

```
let selectedPaymentMethod = require('Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote').paymentMethod().method;
require('uiRegistry').get('dataScope = billingAddress' + selectedPaymentMethod + '.street.0').uid
```

Anyway, in order to get the current billing address field, you must know the selected payment method code.

[image: example from console]

Here are examples when the payment method has been changed (id changing for any new payment method selected):

[image: id changing]